# Building qtcreator from source

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtscript

So I was trying to build `qtcreator` from source, I compiled all the dependencies and moved on to compile `qtcreator`. I got this weird error when i ran `qmake`

`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script`

I did a little googling and found since I've built QT from `git` I gotto run `make module-qtscript`. Bt my question is where do run it. It doesn't run in `qtbase` or in the `qt-creator` source.

Comment: Basically you need to run make module-qtscript in qt5 repository, are there any problems with that?

Comment: Qt repo is the `qtbase` rite? Bt it doesn't work in it. It say no rules defined.

Comment: qtbase is a sub folder of the qt folder you checked out from https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git